# Tablesorter, sort simple number

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

i try to sort simple number like :

`11 256 232`
`256 236`
`23 056`
`11 536`
`1 023 585`

with tablesorter plugin.

But no one of my test is ok.

i try :

```js
$.tablesorter.addParser({
  id: 'colpap',
  is: function (s) {
    return false;
  },
  format: function (s) {
    return s.replace(/\s+/g, '');
  },
  type: 'numeric'
});
```

Do you have an idea ?

Comment: sorting number with tablesorter?

Comment: Yes with tablesorter, my number are in table ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set a "numeric" type for the parser, the sorter is set to evaluate number values, not strings.

So what you need to do is parse the number and return that value

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({
  id: 'colpap',
  is: function (s) {
    return false;
  },
  format: function (s) {
    var number = parseFloat(s.replace(/\s+/g, ''));
    return isNaN(number) ? s : number;
  },
  type: 'numeric'
});
```

* Note: the above parser will not work if your numbers are in European format where commas are used in place of a decimal, e.g. `1 234 545,34`.

I don't know what version of tablesorter you're using, so I'm going to assume it's the original - [here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/eY8uH/1679/).

Comment: Thanks, but i have an other problem :/

I ask a new question !